# JavaScript nested function not refreshing in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, nested-function

I have this JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/4454ve0n/11/

The working code is commented out. I want to move out some lines and make them "global" under `use strict` creating nested functions, following this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_counter3

I'm new to JavaScript.

Someone can explain why my solution is not working in the `widthHeightUnit()` function? It's not refreshing on click, just only if I press F5.

```
(function(){

  ////////////////////////// START OF: NESTED FUNCTIONS //////////////////////////
  var widthHeightUnitVar = (function () {
      var widthHeightUnitResult = document.getElementById('units').value;
      return function () {return widthHeightUnitResult;}
  })();
  console.log(widthHeightUnitVar());
  /////////////////////////// END OF: NESTED FUNCTIONS ///////////////////////////

  window.onload = widthHeightUnit;
  document.getElementById('units').addEventListener('click', widthHeightUnit);
  function widthHeightUnit() {
    //var widthHeightUnitResult = document.getElementById('units').value;
    widthHeightUnitVar();
    //document.querySelector('.width-unit').innerHTML = widthHeightUnitResult;
    //document.querySelector('.height-unit').innerHTML = widthHeightUnitResult;
    document.querySelector('.width-unit').innerHTML = widthHeightUnitVar();
    document.querySelector('.height-unit').innerHTML = widthHeightUnitVar();
  }
})();
```

```js
(function() {

  ////////////////////////// START OF: NESTED FUNCTIONS //////////////////////////
  var widthHeightUnitVar = (function() {
    var widthHeightUnitResult = document.getElementById('units').value;
    return function() {
      return widthHeightUnitResult;
    }
  })();
  console.log(widthHeightUnitVar());
  /////////////////////////// END OF: NESTED FUNCTIONS ///////////////////////////

  window.onload = widthHeightUnit;
  document.getElementById('units').addEventListener('click', widthHeightUnit);

  function widthHeightUnit() {
    //var widthHeightUnitResult = document.getElementById('units').value;
    widthHeightUnitVar();
    //document.querySelector('.width-unit').innerHTML = widthHeightUnitResult;
    //document.querySelector('.height-unit').innerHTML = widthHeightUnitResult;
    document.querySelector('.width-unit').innerHTML = widthHeightUnitVar();
    document.querySelector('.height-unit').innerHTML = widthHeightUnitVar();
  }




  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', dofCalc);

  function dofCalc() {

    var dofCalcWidth = document.getElementById('width').value;
    if (dofCalcWidth.length === 0) {
      alert('Please enter a real value to width!');
      return;
    }

    var dofCalcHeight = document.getElementById('height').value;
    if (dofCalcHeight.length === 0) {
      alert('Please enter a real value to height!');
      return;
    }

    var result = (+dofCalcWidth + +dofCalcHeight) / 2 // The + before the variables is "string to number conversion"

    //document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result + ' ' + document.getElementById('units').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result + ' ' + widthHeightUnitVar();
  }

})();
```

```html
<form>
  Select your width/height unit:
  <br>
  <select id="units">
    <option value="feet">feet</option>
    <option value="inches">inches</option>
    <option value="meters">meters</option>
    <option value="centimeters">centimeters</option>
    <option value="milimeters" selected="selected">milimeters</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>Width:
  <input type="number" id="width" /><span class="width-unit"></span>
  <br>
  <br>Height:
  <input type="number" id="height" /><span class="height-unit"></span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />
  <form/>
  <br>
  <br>Calculation:
  <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question. If jsfiddle is unavailable your question makes no sense to future visitors. [Read the help section on how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way

```
 var widthHeightUnitVar = function () {
      var widthHeightUnitResult = document.getElementById('units').value;
      return widthHeightUnitResult;
  };
```

You were using IIFE so it was running immediately and only once, so it was not refreshing..

```
////////////////////////// START OF: NESTED FUNCTIONS //////////////////////////
  var widthHeightUnitVar = (function () {
      var widthHeightUnitResult = document.getElementById('units').value;
      return function () {return widthHeightUnitResult;}
  })();
  console.log(widthHeightUnitVar());
  /////////////////////////// END OF: NESTED FUNCTIONS ///////////////////////////
```

Comment: Thank You! With this method (and the one I tried first) I created a global variable or not? My whole purpose of this not just code reusability in different functions, but not creating global variable.

Comment: No you didn't create global variable earlier and now also, as it is wrapped in outer IIFE. Keep the outer IIFE, so it wont be in global scope.

Comment: correct, In javascript scope is function level scope not block level, so for a variable the scope becomes whatever the outer function its wrapped in. But beware If you use `(function(){ })();` then you cant access its variables elsewhere.